# How can I order my troops to a specific location?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I've been watching a few tactics videos in order to know how to better position my troops, and I've noticed the players usually place a small flag in order to order their troops to a specific location. However, try as I might, I can't seem to be able to do the same. Looking online did not yield good results.

How can I order troops to a specific location (without the use of mods)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with vanilla Warband is to ride to the location you want your troops at and order them to "Hold this position" with F1 after selecting the kind of troops you want there ( 1 -> F1 would order everyone there ).

If you want to use those Flags like the players in the videos you have seen, you probably should use [Floris Mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/mbwarband/mods/3489/?) to play the game, since this mod adds Regiment Flags.

Comment: Damn, I should have specified in my question "without mods"... Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @NathanSabruka Well the first part of my answer is how you do it without mods. The second parts tells how it was done when you saw it.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold F1 key and a flag will appear on the map. You can then aim it with your mouse.

This works on M&B Warband, no mods necessary.